# MinGW g .exe: Bad file number

Tags: netbeans, mingw, mingw32, msys

NetBeans 7.2.1, MinGW 0.5beta 20120426, msys 1.10.11

After building it throws:

> make[2]: execvp: g++.exe: Bad file number

Any idea? I set the path: Whe I changed c++ compiler column to
mingw32-g++.exe, it works, but when I tried to runa project with some
libraries, then it throws

> make[2]: execvp: g++.exe: Bad file number make[2]: ***
>   [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127

Possible solutions?